# OR condition within IF statement in shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement, syntax-error

I am trying to use 'or' condition within 'if' statement in shell script (Bash/Solaris).
I am trying below, but it is giving Syntax error.

What mistake I am doing?

```
if [ grep "$logtime" $blogs | grep "Authentication Failed" ] -o [ grep "$logtime" $slogs | egrep "AAA Authentication Failure|AAA Authorization Failure" ] > dptest 2>&1;then

    set of commands.

fi
```

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put commands inside `[ ... ]`; this is used for testing expressions.

```
if ( grep "$logtime" $blogs | grep "Authentication failed" || grep "$logtime" $slogs | egrep "AAA Authentication Failure|AAA Authorization Failure" ) > dptest 2>&1
then
    # commands
fi
```

The parentheses in my answer are not part of the syntax of `if`, they're used to group the commands so that all the output will be redirected to `dptest`.